# CMake using shared and static lib

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm currently switching to CMake for my build system (on Windows). I want to build both a shared and a static version of my library.
To include 3rd-party libraries (mostly from github), I run their CMake and install them. I then get a folder /lib/$LibName/cmake, which contains $LibnameConfig.cmake. This can be loaded into my own project using `find_package`, and is overall quite nice.

Now for the problem: Every last library I'm using overwrites these `Config.cmake`-files when building shared/static. From what I found online, I need to link static with static and shared with shared; but that is not possible as the Configs are overwriting each other.
Installing in different folders and then using `find_package` on both also doesn't work, as the package-name is the same for both shared and static (the `.lib` has a different name, but not the package).

As all the libraries I'm using have this overwrite, I thought it might be that my uneducated approach to this problem is flawed.

So, what is the standard way to use both the shared and static version of a library in a CMake-project; possibly switching between both with `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` or a similar flag?

PS: Another thing I tried is pointing `find_package` to a different folder depending on `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`. However, once the package is found, it is not re-searched, so I always and up with the folder associated with the default setting of this switch.

Comment: AFAIR, if you library implementer you should provide multiple targets one for static and one for shared with names like prefixes "-static" or something. If you want you can participate in recent discussion here https://discourse.cmake.org/t/one-library-target-building-both-static-and-shared/3155

Comment: Unless the package provides this functionality in the configuration, you cannot use both kinds of libs in the same cmake configuration of your project. Changing the lib type should be possible by reconfiguring the build dir, but since usually libs store relevant info in cache variables and don't repeat the search, if they found the relevant cache variable(s), you'll probably need to use `unset` before `find_package`. I recommend checking the cache variables in cmake-gui and testing out how the deletion of some entries affects `find_package`.

Comment: *"From what I found online, I need to link static with static and shared with shared"* Huh? From experience I can tell you that linking static libs into shared libs IS possible and I'm pretty sure the other way round would work too. For linking a static lib into a shared lib the static lib needs to contain position independent code, but if it does, there's nothing preventing you from linking it into a shared lib...

Comment: Thanks for the interesting link @SergeiNikulov . :) Also thanks to @fabian for the idea to use `unset`. I was able to solve the problem using `set(LIBNAME_DIR "")`, this forced CMake to re-run the `find_package` command. Would you mind turning your comment into an answer?